# How to stop "Iterate Rasters" after a "n" number of iteration

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, iterator

I have a geodatabase with several hundred rasters. I would like to make an iteration and carry out zonal statistics for every raster in the geodatabase. The problem is, that I don't want to iterate all the rasters at once, I would like to be able to stop iteration after every 12 rasters.

[image: model]

I tried to use Calculate Value to Stop the model after every 12 rasters so if the numeration starts from 0, the first break would be at the raster called `t11`

[image: calculate value query]

But it seems that Calculate Value doesn't work for string values. How is it possible to stop iterating after every 12 rasters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Calculate Value tool is the source of your problems. I have spoofed up a simple model, shown below, note that the Name variable is a *precondition* and not a direct input.

[image: Model]

Below is the Calculate Value tool correctly shown. Note the following:

- In the expression you call the function, you were not doing that
- In the expression you use inline substitution ensuring it was in quotes, you were not doing that.
- The return logic is opposite to what you had
- The return value is a boolean, you had accepted the default.

[image: Calculate Value Tool]

So in this example the model stops when it hits the file name `LT41370441989028XXX02_B6.TIF`.